# $browser->resize(INT, INT); no longer works for me?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

I am currently learning my way around laravel dusk. All of my test were working yesterday, today i get the following error and a blank screenshot.

```
1) Tests\Browser\NewTest::testExample
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnrecognizedExceptionException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: headless chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498537 (cb2f855cbc7b82e20387eaf9a43f6b99b6105061),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

I assume that my chrome may have updated since and no longer plays nice with ChromeDrivers.

Anyone else experiencing anything similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that you need to upgrade to [chromedriver 2.33](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) (your error message shows that you were using chromedriver 2.32).

If you reference this [github issue](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/388), you will see that a user has solved the problem by inserting the following into `composer.json`:

`"post-install-cmd": [
  "cp -f drivers/* vendor/laravel/dusk/bin"
]`

Otherwise, you could temporarily solve the problem by putting the chromedriver 2.33 executable file directly into `vendor\laravel\dusk\bin` and changing its file name to the file name appropriate for your operating system (since you appear to be using MacOS, this filename should be: `chromedriver-mac`).

Comment: This was SO HELPFUL for me! Thanks so much! I didn't realize, but it solved more problems than just the `$browser->resize(INT, INT);` too.